# \asbuk numbering is buggy?

Tags: xetex, numbering, polyglossia, cyrillic, bugs

I have russian alphanumeric numbering in a constantly updating document. Recently, the numbering went terribly wrong. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\else
  \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
  \fi

\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\AddEnumerateCounter{\asbuk}{\russian@alph}{щ}
\makeatother
%\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0mm, label={\asbuk*)},ref=\asbuk*}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\asbuk*}, ref=\asbuk*]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I have the right output using pdflatex (left) and something goes wrong when I use xelatex (right).:
[image: pdflatex output --- right]
[image: xelatex output --- wrong]

Arabic numbering works as expected.

Supposedly, the bug was introduced with the last update no sooner than in October.

Where should I file the bug?
Can anyone point at a workaround?

Comment: Apparently the `polyglossia` developers decided to follow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_numerals and removed the simple alphabetical numbering.

Comment: You can use babel instead of poliglossia with any engines including xelatex and lualatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `polyglossia` developers decided to follow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_numerals and removed the simple alphabetical numbering.

They should have left an interface for using the standard Russian alphabet and not force users to employ the old style alphabetic numbering.

Happily, the code has not yet been removed and we can copy it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{russian}
  \setmainfont{CMU Serif}
  \setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
  \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\else
  \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\fi

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\realasbuk}[1]{\expandafter\russian@realalph\csname c@#1\endcsname}

\def\russian@realAlph#1{\ifcase#1\or
   А\or Б\or В\or Г\or Д\or Е\or Ж\or
   З\or И\or К\or Л\or М\or Н\or О\or
   П\or Р\or С\or Т\or У\or Ф\or Х\or
   Ц\or Ч\or Ш\or Щ\or Э\or Ю\or Я\else\xpg@ill@value{#1}{russian@Alph}\fi}
\def\russian@realalph#1{\ifcase#1\or
   а\or б\or в\or г\or д\or е\or ж\or
   з\or и\or к\or л\or м\or н\or о\or
   п\or р\or с\or т\or у\or ф\or х\or
   ц\or ч\or ш\or щ\or э\or ю\or я\else\xpg@ill@value{#1}{russian@alph}\fi}

\AddEnumerateCounter{\realasbuk}{\russian@realalph}{щ}
\makeatother

%\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0mm, label={\realasbuk*)},ref=\realasbuk*}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\realasbuk*}, ref=\realasbuk*]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I will send them a bugreport then. Thanks for the workaround!

Comment: @PeterMukhachev https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/377 seems to have agreed with our complaints. :-)

Comment: Yes, quite a quick fix, which is very nice!